# 1004 error when defining a range

Tags: excel, vba

I receive 1004 err statement for defining range as follows

```
Set rng(2) = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:" & Chr(64 + columnscount) & RowsCount)
```

I have counted rows and columns before (see below). Could you please advise what's wrong with it? I am desperate.

Thank you very much in advance.

```
 i = 1
RowsCount = 0
Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(i, 2))
    i = i + 1
    RowsCount = RowsCount + 1
Loop


i = 1
columnscount = 0
Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(1, i))
    i = i + 1
    columnscount = columnscount + 1
Loop
```

Comment: Can you write `MsgBox Chr(64 + columnscount) & RowsCount)` and see what is it returning?

Comment: Why not use Cells(): `Set rng(2) = ActiveSheet.Range("A2", ActiveSheet.Cells(RowsCount, columnscount))`

Comment: What is rng defined as?  Are there actually three elements in the array (Remember the second element is rng(1))

Comment: Use as @ScottCraner suggested (should have added it as an answer).  If `columnscount =100 & rowscount = 1` then `"A2:" & Chr(64 + 100) & 1` will return `A2:¤1` - not a valid range.  `"A1:" & Cells(1, 100).Address(False, False)` returns `A1:CV1`.